# How do I create a filtered index on a table type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE
(
    Id INT NULL INDEX ix UNIQUE WHERE Id IS NOT NULL /*Unique ignoring nulls*/
    , Sort INT NOT NULL
    , [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL 
)
```

What's the new way to do this in SQL Server 2016? I keep running into the following error

> Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, a WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Answer (score 2):

From this [Microsoft Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx):

> A nonclustered index cannot be created on a user-defined table type unless the index is the result of creating a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on the user-defined table type. (SQL Server enforces any UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint by using an index.)

I think the only way to create a UNIQUE Index to a Table Type is:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE
(
    Id INT NULL UNIQUE
    , Sort INT NOT NULL
    , [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL 
)
```

I don't think you can add the Ignore NULLS option similar to:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull
ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is about as far as I got too. Unfortunately table types don't allow named indexes, which makes this problematic. I may need to take a different approach to my problem.

Comment: @Matt i agree with that. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This is a little complicated, but if you are willing to add another column, then you can do:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE (
    MyTableTypeId int identity(1, 1),
    Id INT NULL,
    Sort INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    _ix as (coalesce(id, - MyTableTypeId)),
    unique (_ix)
);
```

This assumes that `id` is always positive.

Because `MyTableTypeId` is an identity column, you do not need to insert into it.  You can just specify the columns you want when doing an insert.